# Ruby Backburner Job Results

Tags: ruby, beanstalkd

I'm setting up [Backburner](https://github.com/nesquena/backburner) as a work queue, and my job items need to return JSON for the resulting data they create. I'm not sure how to structure this. As a test I've tried doing:

```
class PrintJob
  include Backburner::Performable

  def self.print(text)
    puts text
    return "results"
  end
end

Backburner.configure do |config|
  config.beanstalk_url    = ["beanstalk://127.0.0.1"]
  # etc
end

val = PrintJob.async.print('some cool text')
puts val
```

and running `Backburner.work` inside IRB. The `puts` works but the return value comes back as `true` instead of `"results"`.

Is there a way to get return values out of `async` methods? Or should I try a different approach, e.g. having one queue for jobs and another for results? If so, how can I associate the result 'job' with the original work it belongs to?

**Note:** I'm eventually using Sinatra and not Rails.